# rails6 / receiving js.erb response from vanilla js request

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, erb

I'm sending simple ajax call :

```
  axios({
    method: "post",
    url,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/javascript",
      "X-CSRF-Token": headerToken()
    }
  })
```

to the following action :

```
def search
  @products = ::Product.search(params[:keyword])
end
```

the .js.erb template get correctly returned, however the javascript contained in it does not get parsed, rather rendered as plain text

[Tried the following](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/How-to-trigger-a-form-submit-from-code) :

```
form = document.querySelector('form');
Rails.fire(form, 'submit');
```

Same result.

What setup is missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer [is here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/36686).

`window.Rails` is undefined, so it has to be imported in the files where it is used.

Then :

```
form = document.querySelector('form');
Rails.fire(form, 'submit');
```

Works as expected